# Error generating entity with Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am generating an Entity from php Class:

```
<?php
// src/Printing/Productesbundle/Entity/User.php
namespace Printing\ProductesBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="UsersStamp")
 */
class UserStamp
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer") 
     * @ORM\Id 
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

}

?>
```

When I execute

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Printing/ProductesBundle/Entity/UserStamp
```

it returns me the following error

```
 [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
  Class "Printing\ProductesBundle\Entity\UserStamp" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.
```

What am i missing??

Thank you!

PS:

That's my Doctrine Configuration:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        # path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
```

Comment: Set a var type like `* @var integer` and `* @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")` and `* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")` for the `$id` property

Comment: It's still giving me the same error :(

Comment: Base on documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#generating-getters-and-setters the only purpose of the command is to generate a proper getter and setter and possible repository class for the entity. I guess if you clear the cache `php app/console cache:clear env=dev --no-debug` then run `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities src/Printing/Productesbundle/Entity/UserStamp` it may work

Comment: I followed your instructions: -Clean cache.. OK (there are two missing dashes before env) -Run the doctrine:generate:entities command, but it's still giving me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying some tricks I found the solution.

I guess the error radicates on the fact that I have entities generated previously from database.

To solve this question, you have to **remove the content of the config/doctrine folder.**

Thanks to @Javad to keep trying!

Answer (score 2):

Could you try command below?

```
app/console doctrine:generate:entities PrintingProductesBundle:UserStamp
```

Comment: Returns an ORMException: `Unknown Entity namespace alias 'PrintingProductesbundle'.`

Comment: Did you define your bundle at AppKernel.php?

Comment: Yes. `$bundles = array(//... new Printing\ProductesBundle\ProductesBundle());`

Comment: Is 'new Printing\ProductesBundle\ProductesBundle()' correct? I thought that it must be 'new Printing\ProductesBundle\PrintingProductesBundle()'

Comment: I have other entities generated in this bundle that had not throw any errors, so I don't believe that's the issue. If I execute the command with the correct bundle name `app/console doctrine:generate:entities ProductesBundle:UserStamp` it returns the initial error.

Comment: Could you change the file name from **user.php** to **UserStamp.php** then try the command?

Comment: The file name is **UserStamp.php** already. The route + filename in the first comment is a typo error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to execute something like this

> php app/console doctrine:generate:entities ProductesBundle

Comment: That command returns the same error because it generates every entity of the Productes Bundle.